# WebPack/Babel: if statement getting altered to negation(!) for react UI

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, webpack, firefox, babeljs

I am running into a weird issue using Webpack/Babel.  I am experiencing a difference between how my code looks in the GUI where I wrote it and in the browser.  I have an if statement that starts off something like this:

```
if (condition1 || condition2 || condition3)
   return;
```

after webpack bundling it looks like this, via the browser debuggers (firefox and chrome):

```
if (!(condition1 || condition2 || condition3))
   return;
```

excerpts from webpack file:

```
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
            plugins: [
                [
                    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
                    {
                        "corejs": 3,
                        "helpers": true,
                        "regenerator": true
                    }
                ]
            ],
            presets: [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                '@babel/preset-react'
            ]
        }
    },
}
```

...

```
output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback:true
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.htm'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: 'process/browser',
        }),
```

...

This has me at a loss as I am not sure how the negation is getting added to the if statement. This is occurring within a button click event.

Comment: I'm sure its some kind of optimization step. Pack with optimizations turned off, maybe that will help. On the other had, can you provide an online sandbox for a little more tesing ?

Comment: would be easier to see the original condition and the transplied one